# XML tools context error

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am currently learning android development for a university module so I am sorry if this is a very basic error. I am currently just following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/), understanding how android java differs to normal java and so on.

On the **XML file activity_main** I am getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol ${relativePackage}.${activityClass}
>   Validates resource references inside Android XML Files

I have used Google and StackOverflow search to look at possible solutions, I found some articles stating it can be due to bad XML formatting which is where I believe the error is. I have also tried to run the project and it cant find the class file R. I have cleaned and rebuilt the project but the error continues to happen.

[Here is my code if you would like to take a look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoR1ByZEY3Z05yZGM/view?usp=sharing). Although at the moment it is very similar to the tutorial website.

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/welcome"
           android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/name"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
           android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/email"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
           android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
           android:text="@string/btn_logout"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is much appreicated, thank you

*P.S I am using Android Studio*

Comment: relativePackage and activityClass are two separate errors

Comment: Post the xml that has the error please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler here is the XML that has the error http://pastebin.com/vcxvRd2R

Comment: Remove your `tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"` tag from the xml and it should solve the issue

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Ah okay thank you, can you please explain what that line is supposed to do? Because it has it in the tutorial. Also why is it that when i try run the application it still cant find R? Error:(15, 63) error: cannot find symbol class R... says Package R doesn't exist this is how i wrote it in the class import android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.R; .... my project is available as a link download above

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error in my layout file and I found this explanation. 
"this is because, there is supposed to be no component added at the time of design. It’s an Empty Activity. If you are wondering what is this “$” sign confusion, rest assured, it is just a way through which the configuration file is letting the runtime understand which Activity class is associated with the layout file."
So, you either can add there your class or remove this line.